# UITextField ignoring shouldChangeCharactersIn with temporary accents

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, user-input

I'm trying to only allow entry of decimal digit characters on an iOS app. I have this snippet that works very well for all situations.

```
override func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let allowedCharacters = NSMutableCharacterSet.decimalDigit()
    let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
    return allowedCharacters.isSuperset(of: characterSet)
}
```

This is as simple as it gets and it was the answer I found everywhere on SO.

**However**, this is where the problem comes in: the accented characters without letters. It's hard to explain this behaviour. When I write a character such as `¨` or `` ` ``, I get in a state where I can follow up with a character such as `e` to result into `è`. This is a pretty standard way for users to input accented characters.

[image]
We end up in this state, where the `¨` is highlighted and I can follow up with `o` to then produce a `ö`.
[image]
 However, the accented character (`¨`) character did not trigger `shouldChangeCharactersIn range` call. It seems iOS decides to ignore that result and still adds in the character.

**How can I block this behaviour**? As far as I understand, this is only reproducible with a hardware keyboard, but we expect our users to use one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user types a combining diacritical such as an umlaut, your method is not called *at all*. Then the user types some other character, such as an o, and your method returns `false`. At that point the umlaut is going to be entered into the field and is shown in `textField.text`. You need to detect this and remove it.

Comment: Interesting that Apple doesn't provide a way for us to intercept this behaviour. As I understand it we will be doing a call on the main thread that re-validates the string, removing any invalid characters that might have been inserted. Thank you for the hint!

Comment: I presume that the runtime can't know, when you type a combining character, what the next character will be. The combining character plus the next character might combine to form a character that _is_ in the decimal digit character set. So it withholds judgment until we see what the resulting combination is. It is odd that returning `false` doesn't cause the combining character to be removed automatically.